# ApacheTop like tool for Nginx for measuring hit contents?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, performance, performance-tuning

Are there ApacheTop like tool for Nginx for measuring hit contents?

I want to find out the most popular URL from the web server log (Nginx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although [Nginx Stub module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpStubStatusModule) might come in handy but i find it less informative than apache counterpart.

For your requirement, [wtop](http://code.google.com/p/wtop/) might be the best.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread and also already answered, but I like to notice that [apachetop](https://code.google.com/p/apachetop/) handles nginx log files as well.
The only thing needed is to modify the nginx.conf file for generating apache like logs. Just add or modify the following line:

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr $host $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $ssl_cipher $request_time';
```